# GAE how to identify blobstore file owner

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

I want to create a directory (folder) on BlobStore in GAE containing multi-files. Does GAE support that? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at GCS if that's how you want to go:

> GCS and "subdirectories"
>
> Google Cloud Storage documentation refers to "subdirectories" and the
>   GCS client library allows you to supply subdirectory delimiters when
>   you create an object. However, GCS does not actually store the objects
>   into any real subdirectory. Instead, the subdirectories are simply
>   part of the object filename. For example, if I have a bucket my_bucket
>   and store the file somewhere/over/the/rainbow.mp3, the file
>   rainbow.mp3 is not really stored in the subdirectory
>   somewhere/over/the/. It is actually a file named
>   somewhere/over/the/rainbow.mp3.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/

So, a "directory" per owner would be the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you plan to use these files.

For example, you can have an entity Photograph with the properties user, title, date, and key. If you need a list of all photographs owned by a user, you query Photograph entities by user id. If you need to access the image itself, you use the key from the Photograph entity.

Note that in this scenario the files themselves can be stored in the Blobstore, in Google Cloud Storage, or anywhere else.

Comment: hello andrei could you please make one simple demo for me,or give me some example i can learn something.

Comment: everyything you need to know ishere: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/introduction